# The switch between tabs works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

I have a problem with switch tabs. In the next snippet you can switch: `vk -> spotify`, `spotify -> vk` and stop. The next `vk -> spotify` doesn't change tab. Why?

```js
$('#sourcePlatform').on('change', function (e) {
    var $optionSelected = $('option:selected', this);
    $optionSelected.tab('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<select id="sourcePlatform">
    <option data-target="#vk_platform">Vk</option>
    <option data-target="#spotify_platform">Spotify</option>
</select>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="vk_platform">VK</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="spotify_platform">Spotify</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

## Update

According [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/list-group/#tabshow) `.tab('show')`:

> Selects the given list item and shows its associated pane. Any other
> list item that was previously selected becomes unselected and its
> associated pane is hidden. Returns to the caller before the tab pane
> has actually been shown (for example, before the shown.bs.tab event
> occurs).

But in this case `active` class hold on previous choose.

Comment: In such a functionality I would expect to find a line hiding tabs before showing the one clicked

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I saw. But I can't understand why this `active` class hold on. According documentation, it must be hidden.

Comment: @Viewed You are using an onchange function hence why its hold. Its does not recognises the change once the cycle is complete. If you do the same thing with `a` then the documentation is correct but in that too => *each tab needs to be activated individually*

Comment: Read [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#tabs-usage) for more clarification => *Enable tabbable tabs via JavaScript (each tab needs to be activated individually)*

Comment: @AlwaysHelping do you know how to change default behaviours in order to it's work with `option` tag such as with `a` tag.

Comment: @Viewed No an `option` tag does not work `a` tag.

Comment: @Viewed Any specific reason you are obsessing so much about about only using `.tab(show)` and not using `removeClass()` to get the desired results ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping This solution is not obvious. Like a stick in the wheel. Conditionally, in a month I will have to dig again and understand why this deletion is necessary. After all, this is not my decision, but the use of a ready-made library whose behavior is changed by me.

Comment: @Viewed No worries. Deleting my answer. Since it did not helped and you have your priorities set!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

u need to remove the unselected option before u show the selected one
first time both of them haven't '.active' className so it works.the third time both of them have '.active' className so it doesn't work

```
$unselected.tab('hidden') // or $unselected.className = ''
$selected.tab('show')
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with bootstrap, but u need remove the unselected option‘s class name of '.active'. use bootstrap api or simply use `element.className = “ ”  `